# Why my component provided from ViewManager is never resize after setText?

Tags: android, react-native

## Background

I'm an Android Native Developer and I am trying to provide a `View` named `CustomView` to react native developer to show it at `ReactActivity`.

The View provided to react native by `ViewManager` is like this:
[image]

When the `SeekBar`'s progress has been changed, the `TextView` below the `SeekBar` will be set a new text according to the new progress.

## Question

In short, why the `TextView` **never remeasure and relayout after setText** when the `CustomView` is added in `ReactActivity`?

When the `CustomView` is added in `NativeActivity`, we can see that the `TextView` can auto remeasure and relayout as expect when we call setText function:

[image]

But when the `CustomView` is added in `ReactActivity`, the `TextView` can not auto remeasure and relayout:

[image]

The `CustomView` xml is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_level"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/seekbar">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_level_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_level_no"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
            tools:text="Hello My Long Level Name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_level_no"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv_level_name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="(Lv1)" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the react native code:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <CustomView />
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          ActivityStarter.navigateToSecondActivity();
        }}
        title="Click to see expected behaviours!"
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
});

export default App;
```

I also have create an [repo](https://github.com/spirytusz/test_rn) to let us reproduce this issue easily